# SQL Join gives more records than expected

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables:

*Table A:*

```
Firstname    |   LastName  | name   |  AC No | code
-------------|-------------|--------|--------|-----
SH           |       RA    |        |  199   |   005
SH           |       RA    |        |  199   |   005
SH           |       RA    |        |  199   |   005
```

--This gives number of records 3

```
 select count(*) 
 from tableA as y where y.[name] = '' and y.[ac no] = 0000199 and y.code = 005;
```

*Table B:*

```
 | name   |  AC No | code  
-----------|----------------
 |        |  199   |   005
 |        |  199   |   005
 |        |  199   |   005
```

--This gives number of records 3

```
select count(*) 
from tableB where y.[name] = '' and y.[ac no] = 199 and y.code = 005
```

--When I join the query like below gives me 9 records. Where as I'm espection 3 records only

```
select count(*) 
from tableA as x right join tableB as y
on x.[ac no] = y.[ac no] and x.code = y.code
where y.[name] = '' and y.[ac no] = 199 and y.code = 005
```

I basically needs to concatenate the "firstname" and  "last name" from TableA and update in "name" in TableB

--what am I doing wrong? How to resolve this issue so that I can get only 3 records?

Comment: The join condition is according to the `code` and the `AC no`. Each record in table1 matches all three records in table2, so nine rows is the expected result. How would you like to correlate them?

Comment: You are joining on a set of non-unique columns (ac_no, code, name). You are expecting three records, but with the existing data, if you used a `DISTINCT` construct, you would end up with one record, not three...

Comment: If there are no other columns in Table A, or Table B, then all the records in Table A are identical. Do you have a PK for either of the tables?

Answer (score 3):

You have three identical rows in each table.  Your join query matches all three items in the second table to each item in the first table.  3x3 = 9.

[image]

Comment: I basically needs to concatenate the "firstname" and "last name" from TableA and update in "name" in TableB - How can I do this? Any example script please? Moreover, i have this where condition  y.[name] = '' and y.[ac no] = 199 and y.code = 005 , then why result is not ...

Comment: @AskMe You are asking for something what was not even mentioned in your original question, the mentioned concatenation problem was added to the question afterwards. Think before ask please. On the other hand, please keep in mind, that SO is not a code generator service, show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this, in two steps:

```
UPDATE tableA
    SET name = FirstName + ' ' + LastName 
WHERE 
    ac_no = 199 
    AND code = '005';

INSERT INTO 
    tableB (name, ac_no, code)
SELECT 
    name, ac_no, code
FROM 
    tableA
WHERE 
    ac_no = 199 
    AND code = '005';
```

Comment: Keep in mind that you presented us with two `SELECT` queries on two tables which have no uniqueness constraints or primary keys, and then you complained that your queries are not doing an expected `UPDATE`. My solution is making the assumption that you didn't want to select anything, but you did want to update some records.